# What is a clean way (or pattern) to do function parameter checking?

Tags: design-patterns, parameters

Is there any design pattern or clean way to do function/method parameter checking (against allowed values)?

Currently, lots of the initial code in my functions consists of these parameter checks (empty strings, invalid characters, existing id, ...) and, while necessary, it is a bit ugly and obfuscates the 'real' code of the function. Typically, my code goes something like this:

```
def my_function(p1,p2,p3,p4):
    #check parameters
    if p1 == ''
       raise InvalidArgError('p1 can not be empty')
    if p1 not in valid_list:
       raise InvalidArgError('p1 does not exist')
    if p2 < 0:
       raise InvalidArgError('p2 can not be negative')
    ...

    #finally do something
    p = p2+p3
```

For the solution, I am thinking along the lines of [decorators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators#What_is_a_Decorator) in Python.
I am using Python, although I guess a good solution would be language-independent.

Comment: Extract the function parameters into a [parameter object](https://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) and make it responsible for validation. That leaves nothing but business logic in `my_function`.

Answer (score 3):

The only fairly language independent thing I can imagine at the moment is some kind of code contract so you can do things like:

```
func foo(param1, param2)
{
    Contract.NotNull(param1)
    Contract.IsIn(0, 100, param2)
}
```

I assume you could come up with an implementation of some sorts in most programming languages.

**Update**

[Microsoft is working on an implementation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) and there is [a Java implementation](http://jcontractor.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I am not familiar with code conracts. Do you have any good starter link? (the results returned by google seemed a bit too high level at first sight)

Answer (score 1):

Each parameter of a method represents an entity. There must be some constraints or assumptions about the argument values based on which the method/the whole class works. So I write methods for validity check of those parameters.

```
void drawRectangle(int length, int width) {
    if (isValidLength(length) == false || isValidWidth(width) == false) {
        // log about invalid argument so that it can be easily traced for debugging
        return;
    }

    // remaining  code
}

boolean isValidLength(int length) {
    if (value < 0 || value > 100) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The advantage is avoiding duplicate code. If null checking, range checking is done for the same parameter type in several methods and sometime later the range for that parameter changes due to requirements modification, then changes are to be made in several places. On the other hand, if the check is done in a separate method, scope of change reduces.

Answer (score 0):

I guess not really, not **one uniform** way to do it.

I personally clarify it in my functions where the real code starts if there is alot of parameter checking to be done (random example):

```
def setpoint(x, y):
    # checking for out of bounds
    if x < 0 or x >= maxwidth: return false
    if y < 0 or y >= maxheight: return false

    # start function
    map[x][y] = true
```

Perhaps you should consider splitting your functions up in smaller functions, to spread the parameter checking.